# Deploying django app on heroku foreman error

Tags: python, django, heroku, foreman

Im trying run my django app on heroku server. My empty django app structure

```
- hellodjango/
- manage.py
- Procfile
- requirements.txt
- venv/
```

in Proc file:

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi
```

hellodjango/wsgi.py:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

I run command:

```
source venv/bin/activate
foreman start
```

and my errors:

```
16:57:12 web.1  | started with pid 3001
16:57:13 web.1  | exited with code 3
16:57:13 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Comment: Don't show a "few" errors. Show the whole lot.

Comment: I changed to my all errors, now I'm sure you can help me :)

Comment: @user3455448 show more errors not few errors

Comment: No more errors shown in my console.